# Access last table in a stored procedure from report builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, sql-server-data-tools

I have a stored procedure witch runs several EXEC commands. As a result it returns more than one table. In SQL Server Report Builder or SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) I can only access the first table it retrieves from this stored procedure. But I need to access last table, in which contains the merged columns from different tables produced by different stored procedures.

I have tried the hide tables other than the last table, but failed. Is there any suggestions you can offer to solve this problem. I appreciate and thank with all my hearth to whom tries to contribute the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem. It is not quite what I have asked but solves this issiue. Here is the solution:

I have edited all sub-stored procedures that I used to "RETURN 0" to prevent them to give an output. So when I call them from Main stored procedure they have no visible output at the "Results" window. Only the Main stored procedure has a single output. Thus I can use it in Report Builder or SSDT like a normal stored procedure without any more modification.